# Rebuild Solution stuck in VS 2015 Update 1

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I have a solution with 83 projects. I'm unable to rebuild the solution. It remains stuck for hours when around 1/6 of the build process remains.

I face this issue only with VS Professional 2015 Update 1. I can rebuild in another system, which has VS 2015 without the update. I could even rebuild the solution with 2010, 2012 and 2013.

Could anyone point out what in the update is causing the issue?

Comment: this is gonna be very hard to answer - I would have a look in the logs to see what project built when stuck and then try to compile them manually and see what is happening. Also make sure to delete all build artifacts or even create a new empty solution and move the projects in again (yeah I know it's a pain) - that's what I would do

Comment: Are you running out of memory?  Check if it uses more than around 1.5GB, if it does, then that might be the cause.  Also check if the Error window are filling up.  More than 1000 warnings here is not good, and VS2015 generates more warnings than earlier versions, due to the Roslyn analyzers.  Note you can also change what to build temporarily in the configuration manager, and using that to try to narrow down which project is stopping you.

Comment: The rebuild was stuck due to a process "find.exe". The rebuild completes once I kill the process. But I have to keep doing it everytime I build

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These build related issues seem to be fixed in 2015 Update 3.

Comment: Unfortunately, not for me.